# When does $A^A=2^A$ without the axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, lo.logic

Assuming the axiom of choice the following argument is simple, for infinite $A$ it holds: $$2\lt A\leq2^A\implies 2^A\leq A^A\leq 2^{A\times A}=2^A.$$

However without the axiom of choice this doesn't have to be true anymore. For example if $A$ is an amorphous set (infinite set that cannot be written as a disjoint union of two infinite sets), then it is actually true that $2^A<3^A<4^A<\ldots< A^A$. The reason these inequalities hold is that $A^A$ is actually Dedekind-finite, so whenever we remove elements we strictly decrease in cardinality.

Of course there are still sets that obey the equation $A^A=2^A$, even if $A$ cannot be well-ordered. For example given any set $A$ it is not hard to verify that $A^\omega$ has the property $A^\omega\times A^\omega=A^\omega$. From this follows:

$$2\lt A^\omega\leq 2^{A^\omega}\implies 2^{A^\omega}\leq\left(A^\omega\right)^{A^\omega}\leq \left(2^{A^\omega}\right)^{A^\omega}=2^{A^\omega}$$
(In fact we can replace $\omega$ by any set $\tau$ such that $\tau+\tau=\tau$)

But I have a hard time to believe that these two things are equivalent: $$A^A=2^A\iff A\times A=A.$$

> **Question I.** Is there anything known on the properties of sets for which $A^A=2^A$?
>
> **Question II.** If $2^A=A^A$ does not characterize the sets for which $A\times A=A$, does the axiom "*For every infinite $A$, $2^A=A^A$*", imply the axiom of choice?

If the answer is unknown, does this question (or variants, or closely related questions) appeared in the literature?

It seems like a plausible question by Tarski or Sierpiński. I found several other questions I have asked before to be questions that have been asked in one a paper or another.

Comment: Given that $A\times A=A$ for all $A$ is equivalent to AC, you could also ask whether the same is true of $A^A=2^A$.

Comment: Eric, yes. That would be the first immediate consequence.

Comment: Because of the question "When does $A^A=2^A$ without the axiom of choice?", I could't help but comment - when A=2...

Comment: Which  for some  reason is  excluded from the initial statement  :)

Comment: I wasn't sure whether or not the additional question makes it eligible for [reference-request].

Comment: (Sierpiński.)${}$

Comment: Thanks Andres, I didn't notice that typo (I can't type the accent on my keyboard, but that's another story!)

Comment: @Daniel Spector, also when $A=0$ (as some people define $0^0=1$). :)

Comment: Does anyone have an idea why this was downvoted?

Comment: Does it known whether $\forall A\,2^{A\times A} = 2^A$ implies $AC$?

Comment: @Yair: That's an equivalent question to the second one I ask here.

Comment: Maybe we can say something like this: take a model of $\neg AC$ in which $\forall A,\,|A|+|A|=|A|$. Now if you have in addition for every infinite set $A$ a set $B$ with $A\leq 2^B$ and $2^{A} = 2^{2^B}$ (sort of very weak $GCH$) then it would follow that $A^A = 2^A$ for every $A$: it is true for $X = P(B)$, since $|X \times X| = 2^{|B| + |B|} = 2^{|B|} = |X|$, and for $A\leq X$ with $|2^A| = |2^X|$, $2^X \cong 2^A \leq A^A \leq X^X \cong 2^X$.

Comment: @Yair: I'm not quite clear on your idea there. Maybe you can explain it tomorrow?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

David Pincus in "[A note on the cardinal factorial](https://eudml.org/doc/215090)" (Fundamenta Mathematicae vol.98(1), pages 21-24(1978)) proves that $A^A=2^A$ does not imply the axiom of choice, therefore it does not characterise the sets for which $A=A\times A$. The counterexample is the model from his paper "[Cardinal representatives](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02760841)", Israel Journal of Mathematics, vol.18, pages 321-344 (1974).

As Pincus writes on the last lines of [Pincus78]:

> c. Our arguments [ in the proof of "4.The Main Theorem; If $x$ is infinite then $2^x=x!$" ] have made little use of the particular definition of $x!$. Indeed let $\mathcal{F}$ be any set valued operation which satisfies:
>
> (1) The predicate $y\in\mathcal{F}$ is absolute from $M$ to $V$.
>
> (2) $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves $|y|\leq x \Rightarrow |\mathcal{F}(y)|\leq |\mathcal{F}(y)|$ and $|2x|=|x|\Rightarrow 2^x\leq|\mathcal{F}(x)|$ for infinite $x$.
>
> (3) $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves $2^x=|\mathcal{F}(x)|$ for infinite $x$.
>
> The statement "For every infinite $x$, $2^x=|\mathcal{F}(x)|.$", holds
>   in $M$ (and therefore is not an equivalent to the axiom of choice).
>   Examples of $\mathcal{F}$, apart from $x!$, are $x^x$ and $x^x-x!$.

Therefore, in this Pincus model, $\mathsf{ZF}$ + $\lnot\mathsf{AC}$ + "for all infinite x, $2^x=x!=x^x=x^x-x!=|\mathcal{F}(x)|$" holds for any set valued operator $\mathcal{F}$ as above.

I should say that, after failing to come up with an answer myself, I found out about this by searching into my good old friend the "Consequences of the axiom of choice" by Howard and Rubin, [Form 200](https://books.google.com/books?id=ffXxBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA50), and [Note 64](https://books.google.com/books?id=ffXxBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA265). I try to reference this book whenever I can :)

Comment: Strange. I know both papers, but I haven't read them thoroughly. I do recall searching the consequences dictionary and coming up short. I also don't quite understand your first paragraph; if it doesn't imply the axiom of choice, how does it mean it *doesn't* characterize? (And I haven't forgotten about the email. I'm writing my reply slowly...)

Comment: Okay, forget about the part I wrote I don't understand. Too much sleep deprivation. My brain is like cheese. I'm not 100% sure that $x!$ and $x^x$ must have the same cardinality, though.

Comment: Well, the consequences dictionary is not the easiest book to search. I searched for this result a few times before I found it. About my first paragraph, I meant characterisation in the sense that for an infinite set $A$, it is not the case that $2^A=A^A \iff A=A\times A$, in particular $2^A=A^A \not\Rightarrow A=A\times A$. What did you mean by "characterise"? (And no problem at all, I'm not in any position to complain about slow email replies :) I also haven't forgotten about updating the file...)

Comment: oops, was writing the comment while you posted yours. I don't know whether $x!=x^x$ either.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think $x!=x^x$ in general. We always have an embedding of $x$ into $x^x$, using the constant functions, but I don't think there's always an embedding of $x$ into the set of permutations of $x$.  Suppose, for example, that $x$ is the set of atoms in the basic Fraenkel model.

Comment: @Andreas: It is easy to see that $x!\neq x^x$ in general, because in the case of a strongly amorphous set, $x!$ is a proper subset of $x^x$, which is a Dedekind-finite set. So there's that (basically, the basic Fraenkel model, yes). But in Pincus model it might be the case after all, which will answer my question.

Comment: In the Pincus model for all infinite $x$, $x!=2^x=x^x=x^x-x!$.

Comment: In fact, according to [Pincus78], whose argument I found to be correct, in the Pincus model:

for all infinite $x$, $x!=2^x=x^x=x^x-x!=|\mathcal{F}(x)|$ holds for all set valued operators $\mathcal{F}$ such that:
(1) the predicate $y\in\mathcal{F}$ is absolute from $M$ to $V$,
(2) $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves $|y|\leq x \Rightarrow |\mathcal{F}(y)|\leq |\mathcal{F}(y)|$ and $|2x|=|x|\Rightarrow 2^x\leq|\mathcal{F}(x)|$ for infinite $x$, and
(3)$\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves $2^x=|\mathcal{F}(x)|$ for infinite $x$. The question now is, what other interesting $\mathcal{F}$ can we think of? :)

Comment: @Asaf, i just edited the answer to incorporate the comments, and try to dispel any confusion with these $\mathcal{F}$, upon which the construction of the model does not depend on.